# Sum by multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have Service which has multiple Tasks. Each Task has a Deduction on a particular Vector.

I'm hoping to Query for all Vector Deduction % by each Vector_id and by each Service.

For example I want:

```
Service   |   Vector   |   Deduction %
---------------------------------------
  SM      |     10     |       5
  SM      |     11     |      10
  ....
  ES      |     10     |       5    
  ....
```

I have got ordered the columns I wish to sum Deduction by, however cannot get the correct group by statement:

```
Select
Service.name AS ServiceName,
Task.name AS TaskName,
Deduction.Vector_id AS DeductionVector,
Deduction.deduction AS DeductionPercentage
FROM
Task JOIN Service ON
Service.id = Task.Service_id
JOIN Deduction ON
Deduction.Task_id = Task.id    
ORDER BY ServiceName, DeductionVector;
```

Here are the tables I am using and some data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea5f70

Comment: Could I help you?

Comment: It's a little strange that the phrases 'SUM' and 'GROUP BY' are both missing from your query

Comment: It would be nice if there was any reaction to comments and answers here at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select
    Service.name AS ServiceName,
    Task.name AS TaskName,
    Deduction.Vector_id AS DeductionVector,
    SUM(Deduction.deduction) AS DeductionPercentage
...
GROUP BY Service.name, Task.name, Deduction.Vector_id
...
```

Note that you should always `Group By` all columns which you use in your `Select` except for aggregated values such as `COUNT` or `SUM`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I was trying to get a total of all deductions for each vector for each service.

Comment: @user3770935 You can remove the `Task.name` from the `GROUP BY` if this solves the problem